# Powerapp component Visibility based on match from Choice (multiple allowed) column in Sharepoint List

Tags: list, powerapps-canvas

I have a SP List that has a column with a Choice selector where the editor can select more than one choice.

In powerapps I am trying to set button visibility based on the choice or choices they make.

I have tried:

```
Filter('Data List',ThisItem.ColumnName = "value")
Filter('Data List', "value" in ThisItem.ColumnName)
Filter('Data List', "value" in ThisItem.ColumnName.Value)
```

and a few other things, but am getting no results.

In PHP we can use in_array() to find a match, I cannot find a similar function in powerapps, but that would be a solution.

In psuedocode:

```
if("value" in column) show button
```

or

```
if("values" in column) show buttons
```

Found a [Solution](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-listbox-control-in-microsoft-powerapps/):

```
If("triangle" in MyListBox.SelectedItems.Value, true)
```